# How to unmarshall Go struct field of type map[string]interface

Tags: go, go-gin

I am trying to unmarshall multidimensional JSON. My JSON is contains dynamic key therefore I can't do it.

**JSON**

```
    {
      "id":"3",
      "datetime":"2019-06-08",
      "metadata":[{"a":"A"},{"b":"B"}]
    }
```

**Go file**

```golang
type Chats struct {
    Id          string json:"id"
    Datetime    string json:"date"
    Metadata  string json:"metadata"
}


chat := models.Chats{}
err := c.BindJSON(&chat)
if err != nil {
    c.Error(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(chat)
```

Answer (score 1):

If metadata is dynamic then treat is as an `interface{}`. If you know it's always going to be a JSON container then you could do `map[string]interface{}` for convenience. There is also `json.RawMessage` if you don't necessarily want to use type assertions to see what's inside of it, but just want to preserve the JSON (I'm guessing this is what you were hoping to do by setting it to string).

```
type Chats struct {
    Id          string      `json:"id"`
    Datetime    string      `json:"date"`
    Metadata    interface{} `json:"metadata"`
}
```

```
type Chats struct {
    Id          string                 `json:"id"`
    Datetime    string                 `json:"date"`
    Metadata    map[string]interface{} `json:"metadata"`
}
```

```
type Chats struct {
    Id          string          `json:"id"`
    Datetime    string          `json:"date"`
    Metadata    json.RawMessage `json:"metadata"`
}
```